# Numerical problem on Viscosity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, viscosity

A horizontal tube of radius $1\ \mathrm{mm}$ and length $40 \ \mathrm{cm}$ is connected to the bottom of a cubical tank of sides $100\ \mathrm{cm}$ containing water of viscosity $0.01 \ \mathrm{poise}$ . From the full tank, water is allowed to flow through the tube. Determine the time in which the tank will be half full.

My Attempt: Using Poiseuille's equation we get :  $$ V=\frac{\pi P a^4}{8 \eta l} $$ where $V=$ total volume that passes through the tube per unit time.

$P=$ the pressure difference between the two sides of the tube,

$a,l$ are the radius and the length of the tube respectively and $\eta$ is the coeff. of viscocity of the liquid.

But here $P$ is a function of time. So I couldn't find it as a function of time.

Comment: [See this post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange).  Physics.SE is not a place for people to do your homework for you.  You should ask about particular concepts you are having trouble with.  You should also include what you *do* understand about the situation, what you have already tried, and where in particular you are stuck.

Comment: I know all that, If you can solve it, give the answer, if can't then please don't give me suggestions like that.

Comment: I've explained why this question is being closed, and what you can do to get someone to actually help you solve this problem.

Comment: And you think there is no particular concept in that question? I explained what i tried, and in what point I faced trouble. What's the problem?